# SharePoint Wiki Page - Hide Columns From Appearing on Wiki Page

Tags: sharepoint, wiki

I created a new SharePoint wiki library and I added additional columns to the wiki library to use as metadata to organize the pages into different views. The issue is now when I create a new wiki page, the added columns appear on the bottom of the page. Anyone know how to hide these columns from appearing on the wiki pages?

Thanks

Comment: I'm away from the office and cannot confirm, but I believe you can accomplish this by using a custom content type instead of adding columns directly to the library. With a content type, you will be able to configure the visibility of each column. Unless I am entirely mistaken, hidden columns will not appear on the wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

Each field has a property "`ShowInEditForm`", which, as its title says, hides the field from editing when the value is set to `false`.

However, you cannot change the value of this property through web interface. What you can do, is create a PowerShell script, which should look something like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://yourserver.com")   
$siteweb = $site.OpenWeb()   
$list = $siteweb.Lists["YourWikiLibrary"]  
$list.Fields["YourNotEditableField"].ShowInEditForm = false;
$list.Fields["YourNotEditableField"].Update();
```